# Complex integration exercise 2

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have to calculate $$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac {\cos x}{x^2+x+\frac 5 4}dx.$$ If I use the function $\frac {\cos z}{z^2+z+\frac 5 4} $ over the contour $A=[-R,R]\cup Re^ {i\theta} $, with $\theta \in [0,\pi] $, I can't show that the integral over $Re^ {i\theta}$ goes to zero as $R $ increases; so I don't know how to proceed. If I use the function Re$(e^{iz})$ always over $A $, I don't know how to calculate precisely the residue in the pole (in $i-\frac 1 2$); clearly that value is equal to the integral requested. Is there another way to proceed, or should I insist with one of the integration above? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $e^{iz}$ approach, you can compute the residue at $z=-1/2+i$ thus,

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-(-1/2+i))(z-(-1/2-i))}.$$
Using partial fractions,
$$f(z)=\left(\frac{i/2}{z-(-1/2-i)}-\frac{i/2}{z-(-1/2+i)}\right)e^{iz},$$
hence
$$\text{Res}(f,-1/2+i)=-\frac{i}{2}e^{i(-1/2+i)}.$$

---

The reason you may choose to use $e^{iz}$ instead of $\cos z$ is because we get the convergence we need, or at least convergence to something which may contribute to the final evaluation of the original integral. For example, in your case
$$\oint_\Gamma\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz=2\pi i\sum\text{residues}=2\pi i\left(-\frac{i}{2}e^{i(-1/2+i)}\right),$$
where $\Gamma=[-R,R]\cup\gamma$ where $\gamma=\{Re^{i\theta}\mid \theta\in[0,\pi]\}$.
We can split the integral up into piecewise paths, i.e.
$$\int_{-R}^R\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz+\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz=\pi e^{i(-1/2+i)}.$$
Now let $R\to\infty$, then we end up with
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz+\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz=\pi e^{i(-1/2+i)}.$$
Now, since $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$, and we know that real and imaginary parts are always independent of each other, then we can *choose* to take the real parts of the equality only. This produces the original integral we were studying in the left hand side, which we can isolate algebraically to get to an answer! Note that in general the integral over $\gamma$ may not always be zero.

In this case, it turns out the integral over $\gamma$ does vanish ! So we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos z}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz=\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+\frac{5}{4}}dz=\Re\pi e^{i(-1/2+i)}=\frac{\pi  \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{e}.$$

Comment: I don't understand why one can just use $e^{iz} $; the restriction of $e^{iz} $ to the real line doesn't coincide with the real cosine function. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Dorian I've updated the answer, hope this helps. Note that $z$ in the final answer is just a symbol to represent the variable of integration, so you can choose to replace that by $x$ if you wish !

Comment: Thanks, so actually what I was missing is that we can use Re$\frac {e^{iz}} {z^2+z+\frac 5 4}$, that restricted to the real line is the function of the exercise. (And for the independence of imaginary and real part the Re operator and the integral commute)

Comment: @Dorian yes, that sounds right !